# Loss of Power of Dual Breaker

Tags: circuit-breaker

Loss of power to part of dual breaker for outside power. Dual breaker stopped working for half last week. Ive tried resetting.

Comment: What make and model is your breaker panel? If you can't tell, post photos here please, so that we can figure it out :)

Comment: Have you fully cycled it off then back on? When you say dual is it a double pole or 2 single poles with handle ties ?  The brand and type would be the other info, some brands do have problems and in those cases we would make different suggestions.